# Iterate over datatable and assign values to different variables

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable containing a list of 6 values. I want to iterate over this table and assign every new row value to a different variable. The table is filled by a class named DataTasks.

This is how I do it at the moment, but I am sure there must be a better, more concise way?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DataTasks.CreateDataTableFromSQL(strSQL);
// Loop counter
int i = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    // Assign ranges - this is where I hope to have better code!!
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            SomeClass.Range1 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        case 1:
            SomeClass.Range2 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        case 2:
            SomeClass.Range3 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        case 3:
            SomeClass.Range4 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        case 4:
            SomeClass.Range5 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        case 5:
            SomeClass.Range6 = (int)row["Range"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Increment counter
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason each of the Range variables are separate variables, and not, say, an array of ranges?

Comment: Can't `Range1`, `Range2` etc be an array?

Comment: I have just amended the code. The six variables are actually class properties.

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE] at least?

Comment: you could theoretically iterate on the Range1 .. Range6 using reflection, [like this](http://ideone.com/j695US), but unless you have like 50 RangeXX variables your current code is much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by the looks of it you're simply assigning the value of 'Range' depending on what row number it is. So why not just do that with out a for loop and do it using indexes. This assumes the number of rows in your datatable is always 6 of course.

Something like this should work:

```
SomeClass.Range1 = (int)dt.Rows[0]["Range"]; //Gets value in 'Range' column in first row.
SomeClass.Range2 = (int)dt.Rows[1]["Range"]; //Gets value in 'Range' column in second row.
//Add more here.
```

Comment: Thanks! This make sense. Since there are always only 6 values, this code will work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing all of the ranges in an array

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DataTasks.CreateDataTableFromSQL(strSQL);
// Loop counter
int i = 0;

int[] ranges = new int[6];

//assuming you have 6 rows
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  ranges[i] = (int)row["Range"];    

  i++;
}
```

Comment: and then loop through `ranges` array to set object props?

Comment: @nvartak Yes, or whatever it is you want to do with the data